# why doesn't my menu float to right side and items are displayed itselfs uncurrect?

Tags: css

Sorry for my English!

My menu is displayed incorrect! The problem: It doesn't located on full container! How fix it?

[image]

The code is here:

```
    <header id="header">
            <div class="center">
                <a href="#" class="logo">SITE NAME</a>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PROJECT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </header>

<style>
/*HEADER*/
/*HEADER*/
header{
       padding: 20px 0;
    /* height: 118px; */
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:300;
}
header .logo{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    color: #637f83;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

    header nav ul {
    /*        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 70%; */
    }
header nav{
    float: left;
    margin-left:50px;
    /* width: 50%; */
    line-height: 46px;
    height: 50px;

}
header nav ul li{
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 0 1%;

}
header nav ul{
    float:right;
}
header nav ul li a{
    color:#637f83;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
</style>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* height: 118px; */
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
}

header .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  color: #637f83;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav ul {
  /*        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 70%; */
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  width: 79%;
}

header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 1%;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style: none
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #637f83;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="center">
    <a href="#" class="logo">SITE NAME</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</header>
```

jsfiddler https://jsfiddle.net/3fw0ynLy/